# Integration of $\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}$

Tags: integration, integration-by-parts

How can I find the indefinite integral which is $$\int \frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}\text{d}x$$

I tried to use substitution by assigning $$\ln(1-x)\text{d}x = \text{d}v $$ and $$\frac{1}{x}=u$$ but, it is meaningless but true, the only thing I came up from integration by part is that  $$\int \frac{\ln(1-x)}{x^2}\text{d}x = foo $$ and that has no help for me to find the integration  $$\int \frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}\text{d}x$$

Answer (score 2):

The primitive is not an elementary function. Since in a neighbourhood of the origin we have:
$$ -\log(1-x) = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{x^n}{n} $$
it happens that:
$$ \int_{0}^{x}\frac{\log(1-z)}{z}\,dz = -\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{x^n}{n^2} = \color{red}{-\text{Li}_2(x)}$$
for any $x\in(-1,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a "well-known" special function: $$\int \dfrac{\ln(1-x)}{x} \; dx = - \text{dilog}(1-x) $$
It is (provably) not an elementary function.  In particular, there is no closed-form expression for it in terms of the functions familiar to the typical calculus student.

Answer (score 1):

This integral has no primitive. Indeed the result is a so well known Special function called Logarithm Integral:

$$\int\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}\ \text{d}x = -\text{Li}_2(x)$$

More here

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function

Comment: No,  the dilogarithm, not the logarithmic integral function which is an antiderivative of $1/\ln(x)$.  Quite different functions, not (AFAIK) related to each other.  Also, you're contradicting yourself by saying it "has no primitive" and then writing down a primitive.